# Androidネイティブ機能で画面輝度の変更

Tags: android, unity3d

質問です。

Androidのネイティブ機能について、マニフェストの
`uses-permission　android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"`関連がうまく動作しません。（画面輝度の変更・取得、フォントサイズの変更ができないなどなど。）
特にエラーは出ておらず、AndroidJavaClassから単に文字列などを取得する他のメソッドはできてます。

```java
//sample.java
public void changeAppBrightness(Context context, int brightness) {
  if (context != null) {
    Window window = ((Activity) context).getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
    if (brightness == -1) {
      lp.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE;
    } else {
      lp.screenBrightness = (brightness <= 0 ? 1 : brightness) / 255f;
    }
    window.setAttributes(lp);
  }
}
```

```cs
//sample.cs
private void hoge(){
  AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
  AndroidJavaObject context = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
  AndroidJavaClass screenMgr = new AndroidJavaClass ("hoge");
  screenMgr.Call("changeAppBrightness",context,100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unityで完結　＋ マニフェストに

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
を追加

//sample.cs

```
private void SetBrightness(float brightness){
#if UNITY_ANDROID　&& !UNITY_EDITOR
        var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        var activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => {
            var window = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow");
            var lp = window.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getAttributes");
            lp.Set("screenBrightness", brightness.Value);
            window.Call("setAttributes", lp);

            int b = 1 + (int)(Math.Min(1, Math.Max(0, brightness.Value)) * 254f); // 1 <= b <= 255
            var system = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings.System");
            var contentResolver = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver");
            system.CallStatic("putInt", contentResolver, system.CallStatic<string>("SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE"), 0);
            system.CallStatic("putInt", contentResolver, system.CallStatic<string>("SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS"), b);
        }));
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ここ（https://qiita.com/GeneralD/items/5e77121cf0b26a103d38）を参考に
Unity側とマニフエストだけで完結できました。